# light switch is apparently broke, but the light stays on

Tags: electrical

my light switch apparently broke with the light on.  Now the light will not turn off. Is it safe to leave the light on overnight with the switch broken?

Comment: Please explain: What does "broken" mean? Did it fall apart? Or ceased it to work without visible damage?

Answer (score 3):

As Ariser mentioned, what type of broke is broke?

If you mean the light switch simply doesn't turn off and on any longer then you should be fine. Any Major electrical problems would either be kicking breakers, making the lights dim or you would smell foul burning plastic. I would however fix it ASAP to avoid even the chance of an electrical fire.